# The difference of method for importing other python files in other directories

Tags: python, import

I know there are some methods for importing other python files.
In the same directory, if I want to import `FCN.py`, I can simply just:

```
from FCN import *
```

But if the target files are not in the same directory, I need to add the path by `sys` or create `__init__.py` in the folder which contains my target python files.

Here's the list of some methods for importing files from other folders:

1. use `sys.path.append('/path/to/python/files')`
2. add `__init__.py` in the folder which contains the python file that you want to import.
3. export the path in terminal (or just write a `setup.sh`), like `export /path/to/python/files:$PYTHONPATH`

Can someone tell me what's the difference between these methods? Or if there are other more elegant ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: Funny.. I just started doing this recenlty:  import sys
sys.path.append('../library/')  and it works fine

Comment: any method that works should be fine. Why you need "elegant" way?. If you develop some open source libraries then putting `__init__.py` is the way I saw in most libs.